# Where is $HOME being set and how can I change it?

Tags: system-settings

I find that my $HOME is wrong and that AWS Secrets Manager relies on this env variable. My theory is that this is why my call to $client->getSecretValue() is failing. Right now it is set to /home/richb201. I know this because echo $HOME  shows /home/richb201. But the real directory should be /home/richb201-XPS-13-9370. I need to fix this to get Secrets Manager working, but don't know where $HOME is being set.

I have looked in /etc/environment but $HOME is not set there. I do see these two lines when I run set:

HOME=/home/richb201
HOSTNAME=richb201-XPS-13-9370

How can I fix HOME to point at /home/richb201-XPS-13-9370 ?

Comment: It is set in `/etc/passwd` file. Check the value there...

Comment: I don't see HOME on passwd. But I do see richb201:x:1001:1001:rich,,,:/home/richb201:/bin/bash

Comment: If $HOME is incorrect, you wouldn't be able to login. I think your theory is wrong. Did you check the content of `/home` with `ls /home`?

Comment: Looks more like you want home and hostname? fred@z170-focal-k:~$ `echo $HOME-$HOSTNAME`
/home/fred-z170-focal-k

Answer (score 1):

It's in /etc/passwd but you shouldn't change that file manually.
With `sudo usermod -m -d /PATH/TO/NEW/HOME username` you can move the directory to the new location and it gets set in /etc/passwd